# UWP VpnManagementAgent problems with credentials

Tags: c#, uwp, vpn

I'm trying to create vpn profile and to connect to it using my credentials. Here is my code:

```
Profile = new VpnNativeProfile();
        Profile.AlwaysOn = true;
        Profile.NativeProtocolType = VpnNativeProtocolType.IpsecIkev2;
        Profile.ProfileName = VpnProfileName;
        Profile.RememberCredentials = false;
        Profile.RequireVpnClientAppUI = true;
        Profile.RoutingPolicyType = VpnRoutingPolicyType.ForceAllTrafficOverVpn;
        Profile.Servers.Add(myserver);
        Profile.UserAuthenticationMethod = VpnAuthenticationMethod.Eap;

        try
        {
            StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            string path = Path.Combine(localFolder.Path, "eap-conf.xml");
            Profile.EapConfiguration = File.ReadAllText(path);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        var profileres = await Agent.AddProfileFromObjectAsync(Profile);
```

profile created, then trying to connect to it

```
VpnManagementErrorStatus status = await Agent.ConnectProfileWithPasswordCredentialAsync(Profile, new PasswordCredential
        {
            UserName = controller.Configuration.Id.ToString(),
            Password = controller.Configuration.Password
        });
```

And it is not working, it either goes to infinite waiting or returns "Other" connection status.
Entering my credentials manually works good, connection established. I tried to invoke connect from code and then enter credentials manually, and I saw that somewhy my login passed incorrectly
[image]

and I'm passing Name as "1005" without dots or any other spec symbol. Will appreciate any hints or help, thanks.

Comment: Can your provide your OS version and SDK target version?

Comment: My OS version is 1803(build 17134.345) and sdk target version is 1803 (build 17134) min version is build 15063

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and found a solution.
Check windows service "Routing and Remote Access" (RemoteAccess). On Win10-1803 we had to run one to resolve the problem. But on 1809 this service is disabled and VPN starting successfully.